# Iterating through an array until random value isn't equal to anything

Tags: javascript

First of all, I am very new to programming so apologies in advance.

This is what I am trying to do:

1) Generate a random value into a variable using

```
questionNr = Random.Range(0, nNodes);
```

2) Compare that variable to an array by iterating through all its values

```
for(var i=0; i<usedQuestionList.length(); i++){
    if(questionNr == usedQuestionList[i]){
        //stuff
    }   
}
```

3) If any value of the array is equal to said variable's value, start from the beginning by generating a new random value and loop through the array again. The only way to pass/end the loop is when the random value is NOT equal to any of the values in the array.

The problem is that if I do this simple for loop, there's no way for me to go back and do everything again when the conditions are not met.

I'm pretty sure I'm just approaching the logic wrong and there's a simple way to do this that hasn't occurred to me, that's why I'm not adding any of the code from my failed for and while loop attempts. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hint: Write a function that does one thing: Check to see whether a number exists in an array, and return `true` or `false`.

Comment: What task are you actually trying to accomplish? It sounds to me like you have an array, and you want to get a random value out of the array?

Comment: So you are reinventing indexOf?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Greg. Led me to the right path. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a flag that you can check after the loop has finished, maybe something like this:

```
//A function that will take a number and check against the array
var loopRandomNumber = function(number){

    //A flag to be used if match is found
    var foundMatch = false;

    //Your simple loop
    for(var i=0; i<usedQuestionList.length(); i++){

        //Checking if match
        if(number == usedQuestionList[i]){
            foundMatch = true; //Match found
            break; // Jumps out of the for-loop to be a little faster
        }   

    }

    //Calling this function again with a new random number if match found
    if(foundMatch){
        loopRandomNumber(Random.Range(0, nNodes));
    } else {
        //Handle your condition for if no match was found here
    }

}

loopRandomNumber(Random.Range(0, nNodes));
```

Comment: You'll want to return the result too... as an aside, recursion probably isn't great for new programmers learning ; )

Comment: This is true, I was originally thinking of using this function just for the check and returning the value, then doing the looping outside of this. Will simplify it a bit :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to vote up, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Got it implemented and working perfectly in my code. Huge thank you! :)

Comment: Your welcome, you should be able to click the tick to accept the answer ;)